# Repeating elements within a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I am currently working on a python script that can generate java domain classes from a model. While working on generating the setters I wrote this line:

```
# sb is a StringBuilder
sb.add('public void set%s(%s %s) {\n\tthis.%s = %s;\n}\n' 
    % (prop.name.capitalize(), prop.type, prop.name, prop.name, prop.name))
```

which outputs the following (with `prop.name = "name"` and `prop.type = "String"`):

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

I feel that repeating the `prop.name` 3 times is a bit redundant, and I foresee that more of these lines will be written before this script is complete. I am wondering if there is a way of writing the tuple more cleanly, maybe something like `(..., prop.name * 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the new string formatter:

```
sb.add(
    'public void set{capital_name}({type} {name}) {{\n\tthis.{name} = {name};\n}}\n'.format(
    capital_name=prop.name.capitalize(), type=prop.type, name=prop.name)
)
```